# Multiple (2) hash url parameters for sorting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, hash

I have 2 filter: by location and by type. Each time I'll need update hash url without refreshing page. How can I do that?

Link structure for example:
site.com/about#location=12#type=188

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I can't give you a specific answer but what you want to do is to use the HTML5 history API https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

Comment: I would use `site.com/about#{"filters":{"location":12,"type":188}}` then you can easily read and manipulate the vars at will

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the hash in the url using `window.location.hash`.

```
window.location.hash = 'some value';
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for... My link looks like site.com/about#location=12#type=188

Comment: You can use this approach. `window.location.hash = 'location=12#type=188';` Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yeah, but how can I check if hash location or type already existing in current url before I adding new I'd to one of hash parameters?

Comment: You can do `console.log(window.location.hash)`. If it returns an empty string, the url is `site.com/about`. If it returns anything else that means you have something after `site.com/about#`.

Comment: For this `site.com/about#location=12#type=188`, it will return `#location=12#type=188`. You can take that string and parse it. Experiment with this in you inspector window

Comment: I need to check if one of them or both of them already existing... If location=19 or type=130

Comment: You need to parse the string. There are no built in methods in JS. You could do something like `var locationValue = ('site.com/about#location=12#type=188').split('#')[1].split('=')[1]` or `var typeValue = ('site.com/about#location=12#type=188').split('#')[2].split('=')[1]` but could probably accomplish this in a cleaner way using regex

Answer (score 0):

first split the hash by `#` to get an array of up to 2 items:-

```
var hashes = window.location.hash.split('#');
```

then you can check if they exist like :-

```
var location = hashes.filter(function(i) { return i.startsWith('location'); });
var type = hashes.filter(function(i) { return i.startsWith('type'); });
```

if `location.length == 1` and the same with `type` then they are set.

then you can update/replace like:-

```
location[0] = "location=" + 11;
type[0] = "type=" + 190;
```

the easiest way to join them back together, encase one isnt set is to add them to a new array and `join`.

```
var arr = [];

if(location.length == 1) arr.push(location[0]);
if(type.length == 1) arr.push(type[0]);

window.location.hash = arr.join('#');
```